# Disable horizontal shift of webview content

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
[myWebView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipe];
[myWebView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipe2];
```

which disables mywebview to scroll horizontaly. Instead it should perform an other method after swiping. It works with iOS 8+ but in iOS 7.1 the content of the webview still gets "scrolled" horizontally. I´ve attached a screenshot to illustrate my problem. I don´t want the gray area on the right to happen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fbTI.png

As you can see not the whole content is shiftet to the left. How can I prevent this "inner" horizontal shift and perform instead a method while swiping to the left? Thx.